# How can I highlight whatever substring I want in a custom drawn string?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, gdi+, gdi

I have been working on my own autocomplete combobox and textbox. At first I just searched for matches that contained as a substring whatever was in the .Text property of the textbox or combobox. That was a pretty intuitive algorithm for the user, so my little borderless listbox-on-a-form popup that showed the possible matches really didn't need to highlight the substring in the possible matches below.

Eventually though I started using my autocomplete controls to search some strings like this:

```
Bob -- Johnson -- 21 Coconut grove -- Age 43 -- Customer ID : 21253
```

I wanted to make it so if the user typed "Bob Coconut" or even "Bob Coco 42" in the box then this record would appear in the drop down, because it contains "Bob" and "Coconut" in the first case and because "Bob" and "Coco" are in it in the second case even though 42 is not.

I want to help the user figure out my algorithm that matches and sorts the suggestions by coloring the different substrings that appear in the suggestions. Here is the code that fills the suggestion popup listbox with one item currently.

```
private void List_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Color bColor = e.BackColor;
        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.PopupSelectionBackColor), e.Bounds);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(" " + this.list.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(this.PopupSelectionForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        } 
        else
        {
            //e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(" " + this.list.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        }




    }
```

What I need to figure out is how to find the coordinates of my substrings in the match string, and then either redraw them as a separate color or run some kind of graphical algorithm over it where all pixels that are the background color in the rectangle containing the text are changed.

I'm not familiar with GDI+. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you're looking for is [MeasureString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you break your string before and after the section you want to highlight, then call MeasureString on each substring then you'll get your start and end points you're looking for.

Comment: This is worth a try. I hope that measurestring is accurate enough to draw me a little rectangle around a lower case "L"!